# Total columns with specific value only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns. A, B and C. I would to add up or Autosum column C but only include (column C) amounts which have column A have as '0' as an amount. Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the SUMIF function, this page explains more about the function in detail.

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php

So your formula will look something like this but with the ranges you require

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$6, 0, $C$2:$C$6)
```